# “could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle” error

Tags: cordova, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I just created a sample HTML5/Cordova project with NetBeans 8.2 and during the Build process, I've faced this error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1).
  Searched in the following locations:

https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.jar
```

Has anyway face this problem before ?
I could successfully download the file, so there is no connectivity problem.

Answer (score 0):

For gradle projects, you need to configure your local or remote dependency repositories inside a closure called build **buildscripts**. It looks like you did not add the correct remote repositories and dependencies, which is **jcenter()** usually. For example, in your root build.gradle, below scripts must be included.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
        jcenter() // the remote repositories. 
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1' // the gradle dependencies. 
    }
}
```